# Removing white space- twenty twelve theme

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to get rid of extra white spaces in my website. I use the twenty twelve theme. This is an image of the update I want to make so if anyone could please advise.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
.main-navigation
{
margin-top: 0.714rem !important;
}
.site-content {
    margin: -0.286rem 0 0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: you should learn how to creat a child theme and make changes over there not in core files so you dont get hurt in updates....

You need go to the CSS file located in your themes folder and edit line 579 wich contains the:

```
margin-top:1.714285714rem;
```

I would change it from `"1.714285714rem"` to **`"10px"`**
also edit line 531 and 541
`.site-content .site-header` u need to change the padding and margins to less value... I would work with pixels its more comfortable

You should work with chrome and click on F12 and left click what you want to edit on the screen and hit inspect element. then you can edit css and see how it looks like before you make live changes.

Hope I helped if there is any other questions let me know.